# cminusminus x86_64 compiler

Tags: haskell, ghc, c-minus-minus

I am working on a project which involves doing Program Analysis on Haskell. I thought that it will be good idea to implement Program Analysis on Cminusminus (C--) level. 
I know that, using ghc, Haskell is first compiled to core then to stg and then cmm. The generated cmm is then converted to executable.

In order to properly understand and work on C--, I need a cminusminus (C--) compiler. However, according to my information, the compilers which compile to C-- are long discontinued and does not compile to x86_64 (e.g QuickC--). Am I missing something? Is there a C-- compiler which compiles to x64?

On a side note, has there been further work on Cminusminus after 2008-09? Is there a Cminusminus community?

**Edit 1**: According to [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/CmmType#CompilingCmmwithGHC) GHC can compile very basic cmm (cmm is a ghc's flavor of c--, which has some differences with c--, however according to my project's needs I should be more concerned with cmm) files. Moreover, the -ddump-cmm contains many items which are not parseable by ghc.

Comment: Can't GHC compile cmm programs?

Comment: Does [this](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Rts/Cmm) help?

Comment: @arrowd I have made an edit based on your comment.

Comment: @HTNW I had briefly skimmed it and some of its links before. However, your comment is certainly helpful, as I need to take this link more seriously.